# Can We Use PHP Session To Protect Files (Video, PPT, PDF, etc)?

Tags: php, video, streaming

Basically, I want to protect my contents, especially my videos, which can be watched online. (streaming)

I know that whatever can be watched can be recorded. but, let's put that aside first...

What I want to know is... is there any mechanism, method or algorithm to use PHP session (username or password) to open a file which is stored in a specific and hard-to-find folder, so even though that file is being stolen, the thief won't get anything. Because they don't have the PHP session id with (username and password).

And, what we're talking here is a web based environment which means I'm not using any desktop software to protect those files.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your file in a folder above webroot. Instead of accessing the movie, have them access a PHP file that sends a content-type header and then does

```
readfile('path/to/file.movie');
```

In that php file, check for an authorized session.